# Deducing a Fibonacci number property.

Tags: solution-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

**Exercise.** Show that, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, the following property holds:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}F_k = F_{2n}.$$

**My solution.** To show this, I procedeed by induction over $n$. For $n=1$, we have that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{1}{k}F_k = \binom{1}{0}F_0 + \binom{1}{1}F_1 = 1 = F_2.$$
Hence, the property holds for $n=1.$ Now, assume that the property holds for some arbitrary $n \in \mathbb N,$ i.e.,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} F_k = F_{2n}.$$
Then, for $n+1$, we have that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}F_k  = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left[ \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}  \right] F_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-1}F_k + \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} F_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-1}F_k + F_{2n}.$$
Now I am stuck. I know that the result
$$ \color{red}{ \sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n}{k}F_{k+1} = F_{2n+1} } $$
Is true and this actually solves the exercise. But is there anyway to solve the exercise without using the result above? Because I feel like if you want to prove such result you would need to use the statement of this exercise, which would make both proofs self-contained (not mathematically correct).

Comment: Maybe , the proof can also be done by using Binet's formula for the fibonacci-numbers.

Comment: Another identical question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532868/305862 obtained using https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: Connected : the same kind of sum but with alternate signs : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4562967/305862